# Testing react applications with AWS Cognito

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, react-testing-library, vitest

I am using react testing library, MSW and vitest. I have a problem with mocking data from AWS cognito. When I try to run the test, I get an error 'NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password' or 'No current user'.

Below is the `setup.ts` file

```
import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/vitest';
import { server } from '../mocks/server';
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { env } from 'process';


Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: vi.fn().mockImplementation((query) => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: vi.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: vi.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: vi.fn(),
    removeEventListener: vi.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: vi.fn(),
  })),
});
const { getComputedStyle } = window;

beforeAll(async () => {
  window.getComputedStyle = (elt) => getComputedStyle(elt);
  server.listen({ onUnhandledRequest: 'bypass' });
  Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
      region: env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_REGION,
      userPoolId: env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
      userPoolWebClientId: env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
      identityPoolId: env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    },
  });
});

afterEach(() => {
  server.resetHandlers();
  cleanup();
});
afterAll(() => server.close());
```

and a sample test

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { UsersList } from './UsersList';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const reactQueryClient = new QueryClient();
const MockUsersList = () => {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={reactQueryClient}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <UsersList />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};

describe('UsersList', () => {
  beforeAll(
    async () =>
      await Auth.signIn('test@test.com', 'test!')
  );
  it('render a list of users', async () => {
    render(<MockUsersList />);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(
        screen.getByText('test@test.com')
      ).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

Any suggestions for mocking user data for AWS cognito?